# I can't understand the last second step.

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

> It is known that $f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_{n}e^{inx}$, with $c_{n}:=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}\:dx$, for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> **To prove**: $$f(Nx)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_{n}e^{iNnx}, \quad N\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$$
>
> **Lemma**: $$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{\frac{i2\pi\mu k}{N}}=\begin{cases}1, & k \mid \mu \\ 0, & k\not\mid\mu\end{cases}$$
>
> Where $\mu\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $N>0$.
>
> If $N\mid \mu$, $N=r\mu$ (say), $e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{N}}=e^{2k\pi r i}=1$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> If $N \not \mid \mu$, $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{\frac{i2\pi\mu k}{N}}=\dfrac{\left(e^{\frac{i2\pi \mu k}{N}}\right)^{N}-1}{e^{\frac{i2\pi\mu k}{N}}-1}=\dfrac{e^{i2\pi\mu k}-1}{e^{\frac{i2\pi\mu k}{N}}-1}=0$ as $e^{\frac{i2\pi\mu k}{N}}-1\neq0$ as $N \not\mid \mu$.
>
> **Proof**: $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(Nx)e^{-inx}\:dx=\int_{0}^{2Nx}f(y)e^{-\frac{iny}{N}}\:\frac{dy}{N}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(y)e^{-\frac{iny}{N}}\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{\frac{-2\pi i k n}{N}}\right)\:dy,\quad y=Nx$$
>
> $$=\begin{cases}2\pi c_{n}, & \frac{n}{N}\in\mathbb{Z} \\ 0, & \frac{n}{N}\not\in\mathbb{Z}\end{cases}$$

In the course of the proof，I can't understand the second step.I need a detailed derivation.

Comment: I undertand the couse of the lemma,but i can't understand the course of prove,especially from the first line to the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the proof shows the following: given a $2\pi$ periodic function $f(x)$ and its Fourier coefficients $c_n$, how can we obtain the Fourier coefficients of the function $f(Nx)$ in terms of the coefficients $c_n$? Here is how I would show what the Fourier coefficients of $f(Nx)$ are:

$$d_n=\frac{N}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi/N}f(Nx)e^{-inx}\;dx =\\
=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(y)e^{-iy\frac{n}{N}}\;dy$$

where I've substituted $y=Nx$ and used the fact that $f(Nx)$ is $2\pi /N$ periodic. Now we replace $f(y)$ in the integral by its series representation:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(y)e^{-iy\frac{n}{N}}\;dy=\\
=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sum_k c_k e^{iky} e^{-iy\frac{n}{N}}\;dy=\\
=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_k c_k \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{iy(k-\frac{n}{N})}\;dy$$

The integral can easily be shown to evaluate to

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{iy(k-\frac{n}{N})}\;dy =
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}2\pi,\quad n=kN\\0,\quad \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

So for $d_n$ we get

$$d_n = \left\{\begin{array}{l} c_{n/N},\quad n=kN\\
0,\quad\text{otherwise}\end{array} \right.$$

**EDIT**: thanks Shaktal, now I can finally read the proof well, but I guess it's similar to what I have shown. Anyway, the result remains the same.

**EDIT 2**: Concerning the original proof, there is a mistake in the upper integration limit. It must be $2N\pi$ instead of $2Nx$. With this in mind, the integral from $0$ to $2\pi N$ is split up in $N$ integrals like this:

$$\int_{0}^{2N\pi}f(y)e^{-\frac{iny}{N}}\frac{dy}{N}=
\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\int_{2k\pi}^{2(k+1)\pi}f(y)e^{-\frac{iny}{N}}\frac{dy}{N}=\\
\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(y)e^{-\frac{in(y+2k\pi)}{N}}\frac{dy}{N}=\\
\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(y)e^{-\frac{iny}{N}}\frac{1}{N}
\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{-\frac{2\pi ikn}{N}}dy$$
where we have used the fact that $f(y)$ is $2\pi$ periodic.

Comment: Can you explain the course of proof in my question? There is a mistake in your answer,please check up carefully.

Comment: In the second line of your answer,shouldn't the upperlimit be 2Npi?

Comment: When you posted it, the proof was close to unreadable. (Thanks to Shaktal for improving it!) So I tried to help you with a simple proof that shows the same result. If there's a mistake somewhere I would be grateful if you could point out where it is, so I can correct it.

Comment: Thank you for your simple proof! But I really want to understand what the expressions say in my question!I can't understand the first line of the proof in my quesetion especially.

Comment: @parkning: Ah right, I messed up with the integration limits, thanks for pointing it out. I've already corrected it, the result remains the same of course.

Comment: @parkning: I've added my explanation of the original proof to my answer.

Comment: Welcome! If you're happy with it, you can accept my answer, so people know that the problem has been solved.

Comment: The second line in EDIT 2 should be y-2kpi.The expression in my question is wrong also.

Comment: No, it's correct: $\int_{2k\pi}^{2(k+1)\pi}g(x)dx=\int_{0}^{2\pi}g(x+2k\pi)dx$